# XSLT 3.0: Divide into groups when there is a direct appeal to the element

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to divide the xml into pages, where whenever there is an `<eop>` tag a new page starts.
I have calls specific elements, and I see that it destroys the division ..
When I put in the group:                    `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>`
That was fine.
And because I changed to a specific call:                     `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/self::title"/> <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/self::article"` it was destroyed ..

Anyone have an idea how to make specific calls in group ?

the xml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataRoot >
    <eop eId="100"></eop>
    <article>
        <content>
            <p>page 100 article 1 p 1</p>
        </content>
        <title>article 1</title>
        <content>
            <point>
                <p>page 100 article 1 p 2</p>
                <p>page 100 article 1 p 3
                    <p>page 100 article 1 p 4
                        <eop eId="101"></eop>
                        page 101 article 1 p 5
                    </p>
                    <p>page 101 article 1 p 6</p>
                </p>
                <p>page 101 article 1 p 7

                </p>
            </point>
            <point>
                <p>page 101 article 1 p 8</p>
            </point>
        </content>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>article 2</title>
        <content>
            <point>
                <p>page 101 article 2 p 1</p>
                <p>page 101 article 2 p 2

                </p>
            </point>
        </content>
    </article>
</dataRoot>
```

the xslt:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:text="my-namespace-uri" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0" >
    <xsl:function name="text:direction">
        <xsl:param name="element"/>
        <xsl:variable name="eId" select="$element/preceding-sibling::eop[1]/@eId"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="
            if (number(translate($eId, translate($eId, '0123456789', ''), '')) mod 2 = 0) then
            'dir_rtl' 
            else 
            'dir_ltr'
            "/>
    </xsl:function>
    <xsl:mode use-accumulators="#all" streamable="no"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:accumulator name="directionByPage" as="xs:string?" initial-value="'dir_rtl'">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="eop" select="if (number(translate(@eId, translate(@eId, '0123456789', ''), '')) mod 2 = 0) then 'dir_rtl' else 'dir_ltr'"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    .dir_rtl{   text-align: right;   display: grid;    direction: rtl;    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;                   }
                    .dir_ltr{    text-align: right;  display: grid;    direction: ltr;    grid-template-columns: 15% 85%;                   }
                    .page{
                    margin: 7em;
                    background-color: rgb(68,68,68); /* Needed for IEs */
                    
                    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
                    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgb(68 68 68 / 60%);
                    
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
                    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
                    zoom: 1;
                    }
                    .page .content {
                    position: relative; /* This protects the inner element from being blurred */
                    padding: 1em 2em;
                    background-color: #ffff;
                    }
                   
                   .eop{padding:2em;}
                    .numPage{padding:1rem 1rem 1rem 2rem;}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dataRoot">
        <xsl:for-each-group select=".//node()" group-starting-with="eop">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="content">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/self::title"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/self::article"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="eop">
        <div class="numPage">
              number page:
            <xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::node()/@eId"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="article" >
        <div class="article">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::node()/text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="content" >
        <div class="content">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="point">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p" >
        <div class="p">
            <xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::node()/text()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result:
[image]

The page should end in eop 101
And instead ends at the end of Article 1

Comment: If `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` did the job why do you need to change it? Or what result did you get with `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` that you need to change? Normally if you group all elements in a nested hierarchy because your end of line or end of page marker can be at any level, you somehow need to make sure you push only the current group through your templates, as done, for instance, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887554/252228

Comment: I want the view to be different from the xml hierarchy
, Meaning that a title will be displayed first even if there is an article in front of it.
I tried the example you suggested, it does solve the problem of division into pages but does not called to the  templates (example:<xsl:template match="title">) that is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use two different modes, where you process all elements but the `title` in one mode that outputs the hierarchy of the current-group but blocks the `title` and the other outputs e.g. the `title`:

```
  <xsl:template match="dataRoot">
      <xsl:variable name="parent" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::node()" group-starting-with="eop">
          <div class="page">
            <div class="content">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::title]"/>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="$parent/node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()]" mode="subtree"/>
            </div>
          </div>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="eop" mode="subtree"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="subtree">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()]" mode="subtree"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="article/title" mode="subtree"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="article/title">
    <h2>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h2>
  </xsl:template>
```

Probably mapping the `article/title` to an `h2` element is not what you want but of course you can let that template matching `article/title` create any output you want, so let that particular example above not confuse you, I just needed some way to distinguish the "special" processing of the `title` in the output from the processing of the rest of the group.

As for your comments, your own templates would be adapted e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="content" >
    <div class="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

would become

```
<xsl:template match="content" mode="subtree">
    <div class="content">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()]" mode="subtree"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But if I do that then the other templates will not be read (no div tags are displayed etc)
Only a title format is read, and I want it to read them all.
I need to wrap each element in div

Comment: Of course just add any templates you have/ need, just make sure you use two modes.

Comment: And anywhere you process the current group and want to apply templates to child nodes make sure you have e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()]" mode="subtree"/>` instead of a simple `<xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>` otherwise children/descendants "leak in" which were not part of the group/page.